# how can i play alarm with notification in iphone

Tags: iphone, notifications, alarms

i want to play multiple alarm in my application with notification can i play alarm ?...

how can i play multiple alarm with notification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement local notifications. read this [tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)

Comment: ya i know this but how ? .i m new in iphone world so don't know more abt iphone so can u give me code for this ?